# Razor/C# date to Javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a Razor/C# date coming from a controller I am calling from jQuery AJAX.  The controller triggers and I am pulling it back through HttpContext.Current.Session in my View.

I am getting a date back when I debug the View and the Razor, BUT the issue is I keep getting date to format correctly in the Javascript. I keep trying to console out the output and it keeps giving me an error:
"Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list"

The output in Chrome's Developer window is:
[image: Session Date Issue]

You can see that for some reason teh date is either not converting to a string properly or there is some sort of formatting happening that I am just not seeing or understanding.  Any help is appreciated.

My JS and Razor is below:

```
 function UpdateShowTimeList() {
     @{ 
         var dateFromHubTimeList = DateTime.MinValue;
         var objTimeList = HttpContext.Current.Session["CalendarSelectedDate"];

         if(objTimeList != null)
         {
             dateFromHubTimeList = Convert.ToDateTime(objTimeList);

         }

     }
   //Keep getting error on this line and have NO idea why
    console.log("Session Selected Date Show Time List: " +  @dateFromHubTimeList.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm"));


  //jQuery AJAX is here and is working.
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following code in your `console.log`:

```
'@dateFromHubTimeList.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm")'
```

> **Note:** I put **single quotes** around my `Razor` code to make its result as js `string`.

Example:

```
console.log("Session Selected Date Show Time List: " +  
            '@dateFromHubTimeList.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm")');
```

Also you have another options for different cases

```
'@dateFromHubTimeList.ToShortDateString()'
'@dateFromHubTimeList.ToLongDateString()'
'@dateFromHubTimeList.ToShortTimeString()'
```

Comment: Oh my gosh man, rookie mistake on my end. Thank you for pointing out the obvious.

Answer (score 2):

You need to include the output from C# *within* the JS string:

```
console.log('Session Selected Date Show Time List: @dateFromHubTimeList.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm")');
```

Comment: This works same as RAM's solution.  I will repeat, thank for pointing out the obvious to me. Rookie mistake on my part, even though I should have known this.